# duplicity resends all the data if filename is renamed

Tags: linux, rsync, backup, duplicity

Let's create a `test/` directory containing a random 1 GB file: `head -c 1G </dev/urandom >test/1GBfile`,
and let's do a backup with [duplicity](http://duplicity.nongnu.org/):

```
duplicity test/ file:///home/www/backup/
```

Then `/home/www/backup/` contains an encrypted archive, taking around ~1 GB.

Then let's add a new file of a few bytes: `echo "hello" >test/hello.txt`, and redo the backup:

```
duplicity test/ file:///home/www/backup/
```

The `backup/` is still ~ 1 GB. Only a few files were created of < 1 KB, as usual in incremental backup.

**Now let's rename the 1 GB file: `mv test/1GBfile test/1GBfile_newname` and redo the incremental backup**:

```
duplicity test/ file:///home/www/backup/
```

**Then `backup/` is now ~ 2 GB!**.

Why does `duplicity` not take into account the fact it's the same file content with a new name?

Here if we had used networking, we would have wasted 1 GB transfer even if the file content is exactly the same. `duplicity` uses `rsync` which usually takes care of this problem, is there an option to avoid this problem?

---

Log after the addition of the .txt file:

```
--------------[ Backup Statistics ]--------------
StartTime 1605543432.43 (Mon Nov 16 17:17:12 2020)
EndTime 1605543432.72 (Mon Nov 16 17:17:12 2020)
ElapsedTime 0.29 (0.29 seconds)
SourceFiles 3
SourceFileSize 1073745926 (1.00 GB)
NewFiles 2
NewFileSize 4102 (4.01 KB)
DeletedFiles 0
ChangedFiles 0
ChangedFileSize 0 (0 bytes)
ChangedDeltaSize 0 (0 bytes)
DeltaEntries 2
RawDeltaSize 6 (6 bytes)
TotalDestinationSizeChange 230 (230 bytes)
Errors 0
-------------------------------------------------
```

Log after the renaming of the file:

```
--------------[ Backup Statistics ]--------------
StartTime 1605543625.97 (Mon Nov 16 17:20:25 2020)
EndTime 1605543840.72 (Mon Nov 16 17:24:00 2020)
ElapsedTime 214.76 (3 minutes 34.76 seconds)
SourceFiles 3
SourceFileSize 1073745926 (1.00 GB)
NewFiles 2
NewFileSize 1073745920 (1.00 GB)
DeletedFiles 1
ChangedFiles 0
ChangedFileSize 0 (0 bytes)
ChangedDeltaSize 0 (0 bytes)
DeltaEntries 3
RawDeltaSize 1073741824 (1.00 GB)
TotalDestinationSizeChange 1080871987 (1.01 GB)
Errors 0
-------------------------------------------------
```

`TotalDestinationSizeChange 1080871987 (1.01 GB)`, arghh! The file has just been *renamed*!

Comment: Consider using `restic` instead?

Comment: @Kusalananda does it do encrypted storage in destination (i.e. encrypted locally and destination NEVER ever has the decrypted content)? Which option does this with `restic`?

Comment: `restic` encrypts by default. Check out the documentation https://restic.net/

Comment: For future reference, can you post an answer with an example command-line command to do this with restic @Kusalananda?

Comment: Hmm... That would not be an answer to your question though. I have no experience of using `duplicity`, so someone that has may still be able to help you with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that `duplicity` does not "handle renames" indeed, see this column here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Synchronization_and_backup_programs#Chunk-based_increments

Since `duplicity` uses `librsync` (that [does not "handles renames"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/620070/is-it-true-that-rsync-does-not-handle-file-renames-gracefully/620080#620080)), it seems normal.